# What does this JavaScript syntax mean in regards to .unshift()?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code on a tutorial and I don't know what is going on in the unshift method. I understand what .unshift() does in js, but I don't understand what this syntax is doing, specifically the fact that it is written as x:x and y:y.

```
insert: function(x, y) {
        this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y}); // unshift prepends an element to array
        this.last = this._queue[0];
    },
```

Comment: _queue is an array of x and y coordinatse. e.g., `_queue = [ {x:10,y:20}, {x:11,y:30} ];` does that help? x and y are variables

Comment: yes, thanks for the clarification

Comment: it's unshifting an object that has two keys, x and y, whose values are the values of the function arguments, x and y - note, ES2015 (or 2016, never sure) shorthand would be `this._queue.unshift({x, y});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unshifting an element to an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) simply inserts that element into the front of the array.

Here, we have some array called `_queue` in which we are inserting `{x:x, y:y}` to the front.

So if the queue looked something like this:

```
_queue: [
  {x:1, y:1},
  {x:2, y:2},
  {x:3, y:3},
  ...
];
```

it now would look something like this:

```
_queue: [
  {x:x, y:y}, // what you had just inserted
  {x:1, y:1},
  {x:2, y:2},
  {x:3, y:3},
  ...
];
```

The `insert` function where this is being called takes two parameters of `x` and `y`, so when we insert an object like:

```
{x:x, y:y}
```

What this really means is that we're inserting an object who's fields are:

```
{
  x: x, //(whatever argument was passed in for `x` when the function was called)
  y: y  //(whatever argument was passed in for `y` when the function was called)
}
```

Comment: he said he knows what unshift does

Comment: @KeithNicholas I'm aware of that, but it doesn't mean I'm not allowed to quickly go over what it does for the sake of completeness. I also updated my answer to cover more info

Answer (score 1):

It's adding an object to the array, so if the array was previously empty, it will now look like this:

```
[
  {
    x: "whatever the value of x was passed into that method", 
    y: "whatever the value of y was passed into that method"
  }
]
```

As to why? I have no idea without seeing the entirety of the code

Answer (score 1):

```
{x:x,y:y}
```

is odd syntax when you first come across it, but in javascript, the key can't be a variable so is treated as a literal, and the value is the variable.

so if `x =1;`

```
var o = {
  x:x
}
```

will mean `o = {x:1}`

if you did want the key by variable then you'd use something like

```
var x = 1;
var key = "x";
o = {}
o[key] = x;
```